# Check if null VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, textbox, null

having trouble working out why this won't check the textbox too as well as the selected color. 
 If I do not put a color it flags up the "please enter fields" message, however if I do select a color but do not put anything in the name textbox then it carries on and just outputs a blank string in the msgbox.

Code is:

```
 Dim newColor As Color
Dim userName As String
Dim notEnoughArguments As String = "Please fill out the fields"


'Click event for button
Private Sub enterBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles enterBtn.Click

    If (userName Is "") Then

        MsgBox(notEnoughArguments)

    ElseIf (userName Is "" And colorLtb.SelectedItem Is Nothing) Then

        MsgBox(notEnoughArguments)

    ElseIf (colorLtb.SelectedItem Is Nothing) Then

        MsgBox(notEnoughArguments)

    Else

        userName = txt1.Text
        Dim selectedColor As String = colorLtb.SelectedItem.ToString
        newColor = Color.FromName(selectedColor)
        Dim msgBoxText As String = "Hello " + txt1.Text + "." & vbCrLf + "Changing your color to " + selectedColor + "."
        MsgBox(msgBoxText)

        Me.BackColor = newColor

    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Realised i'm only checking that they're both done, but when putting them into seperate if's with an elseif it still doesn't work? - Edited main post to show new code. Still having the same problem with it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For strings (like your textbox contents) use `String.IsNullOrWhitespace` as a test. Also you want both arguments, right? So a single statement should do:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) OrElse colorLtb.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
    MessageBox.Show(notEnoughArguments)
    Return
End If
```

The problem is that `Dim userName As String` means the variable has nothing at all and that is not the same as an empty string. I always declare strings and immediately set them to `String.Empty` to avoid null reference exceptions, but using `String.IsNullOrEmpty` is a clean and robust way to test the contents of a string variable.

Comment: That should be an `Or`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and explanation. Is really helpful. I've done that but with an 'or' not an 'and'. It now works like a charm. Thanks a lot for the help. And the explanation once again, I'll definitely continue these rules when developing later projects.

Comment: Quite right @NicoSchertler! My mistake, was dashing off to a scrum call and didn't read back! In fact, made it an `OrElse` as it never hurts to have a bit of short-cutting in there since if the first test fails there is no need to run the second.

Answer (score 0):

Normally to test for equality in VB, you use a single = rather than Is

```
If (userName = "") Then
```

When testing for Nothing, you have to use Is

```
If (userName Is Nothing) Then
```

IsNullOrEmpty combines both tests. As the accepted answer suggests:

```
If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName)) Then
```